# JS: Assignment within if statment doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random, variable-assignment

I have a twodimensional array and want to set a random elements value to 2.
My attempt is the following, but that didn't work..
If the random value is undefined, then set it to 2, if not repeat.
Thanks in advance!

```
var randomTileFunction = function (board) {
  var randomTile = board[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  if(randomTile === undefined) {
    randomTile = 2;
  } else {
    randomTileFunction(board);
  }
};
```

Comment: "but that didn't work" - what happens?

Comment: i log the array afterwards and it stays the same.
Webstorm says on line 4: "The value assigned is never used"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randomTile` is a variable whose assigment does not affect another variable `board[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]`.

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
if(board[i][j] === undefined) {
  board[i][j] = 2;
```

Comment: thanks, that worked!
btw: is it good practice to call function again?

Comment: it is normal practice, if your logic requires recursion